# The cancel button from prompt would not cancel properly, but continues to the next alert. Can anyone explain?

Tags: javascript, prompt

below is the code I have been trying to make work. Everything is working, except when cancel button is pushed, it still goes to the alert of wrong answer and would not break the function properly. I cannot understand why. Can anyone enlighten me please?

```
    let question = theQuestion;
    if (question === null || question === '' || question === 'null') {
        // console.log(`game canceled`);
        return;
    } else if (question == rightAnswer) {
        console.log('right answer');
        return true;
    } else if (question !== rightAnswer && question !== null && question !== '' && question !== 'null') {
        alert(`You lost!`);
        console.log('game lost')
    }
}
et question1 = `What is my name? 1. Rashad 2. Rashid 3. Richard 4. Alovsat`;
let question2 = `What is my age? 1. 23 2. 25 3. 28 4. 30`;
let question3 = `How tall am I? 1. 190cm 2. 188cm 3. 192cm 4. 198cm`;

if (checkQ(+prompt(question1), 1)) {
    alert(`You have 100 points`);
    if (checkQ(+prompt(question2), 2)) {
        alert(`You have 500 points`);
        if (checkQ(+prompt(question3), 3)) {
            alert('You won!');
        }
    };
} else {
    console.log(`game lost`)
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle?

Comment: Without seeing what `checkQ` does it's hard to confirm, but clicking cancel will return `null`. When you do `+null`, you get `0`. So, is there a reason `checkQ` will not behave as expected when you call `checkQ(0, n)`?

Comment: You should be just doing like `if(+prompt(question3) === 3){ }`. Your `checkQ` function is ridiculous. It never tests for `3` in the last prompt result. But really, there's just no point for it here. Oh, and don't use `prompt` or `alert` in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const rightAnswers = ['Rashad','25','188cm'];

const questions = [
  `What is my name? 1. Rashad 2. Rashid 3. Richard 4. Alovsat`,
  `What is my age? 1. 23 2. 25 3. 28 4. 30`,
  `How tall am I? 1. 190cm 2. 188cm 3. 192cm 4. 198cm`
];
const points = [100,200,500];

function checkQ(answer, idx){
    if (answer === null) {
        console.log(`game canceled`);
        return null;
    } else if (answer == rightAnswers[idx]) {
        console.log('right answer');
        return true;
    } else if (answer != rightAnswers[idx]) {
        alert(`You lost!`);
        console.log('game lost')
        return false;
    }
}
const size = questions.length;
let correctCount = 0;
let point = 0;
questions.forEach(function( question, index ) {
  if (checkQ(prompt(question), index)) {
    correctCount +=1;
    alert("You have "+points[index]+" points");
  }
});

if(size==correctCount){
  alert('You won!');
}

</script>
```